# Hibernate: HQL join query on association doesnt result as expected

Tags: hibernate, associations, hql, inner-join

I have a two classes 
`User` and `article`

`User` has a `one-to-many` relationship with article

> I want to get an article by the user's `username` and article's `id`

```
select distinct user.articles
     from User as user inner join user.articles as article
     where article.user.username = 'sammer' and article.id = 8
```

I am getting the same result as expected with just `where article.user.username = 'sammer'` or no result if the id doesn't match with an article written by the user
 while I add the another restriction  as `article.id =8`. it again shows all the results. It is supposed to provide a unique result or no result at all.

> Ex: Suppose user has written article with id's 8,9,10. when I hit the above query, it gives all the 3 results. But if I change the id to anything except the 8,9,10. It doesn't show any result. but it shows all the results when the id is any of the 8,9 or 10

please give your advice. I might be doing something wrong. 
Thank you for your time!

Comment: You are querying for the user's collection of articles. So you will get all the collection if match the conditions or nothing. Review what do you want to achieve, maybe you write something wrong

Comment: what i dont get is.
whether I query the data from User's articles or from Articles directly. I mean the queries should work as long as the conditions matches data. Why does it return all the data?

Comment: mm.. I better write you an answer to be more clear... take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the articles satisfying the filter criteria:

```
select a
from Article a
where a.user.username = 'sammer' and a.id = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get an article by the user's username and article's id

Like @DraganBozanovic says, you just need to query for an `Article` and not throught the `User`'s collection of articles like you do `select distinct user.articles ...`

> Suppose user has written article with id's 8,9,10. when I hit the
>   above query, it gives all the 3 results. But if I change the id to
>   anything except the 8,9,10. It doesn't show any result. but it shows
>   all the results when the id is any of the 8, 9 or 10

When the conditions `article.user.username = 'sammer' and article.id = 8` match you have found an specific `Article` linked to some user but then you **ask for the user's articles** `select distinct user.articles` instead of getting for the article you just found. This is why you finally get all the user's articles 8, 9, 10.

If you want to get the article 8, do something like:

```
select distinct article
     from User as user inner join user.articles as article
     where article.user.username = 'sammer' and article.id = 8
```

That will return the article or none/exception when *article.id* 8 doesn't exists or its linked user have other *name*.

Comment: Ok. But I had used user.articles in the select clause.
you used article which is alias to user.articles. Doesn’t both of them represent same objects? Just a thought

Comment: No, it doesn't represent the same. With the alias "article" you refer to all articles that have association within some user. But "user.articles" refers to all articles of a specific user. Other comment, for the @Dragan's answer don't forget to add the disctinct keyword because it won't work as you wish if there are articles with same id attribute value.